# Concatenate 2 Enumerated type variable sets

Tags: enums, minizinc

```
enum sup;
sup=['a','b','c'];


enum sup2;
 sup2=['d','e','f'];

enum sup3;
sup3=sup++sup2;
```

I want to get an new enumerated type sup3 with all a,b,c,d,e,f.Is there any way in minizinc we can do this.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no, this is currently not supported. The main issue with the concatenation of enumerated types comes from the fact we are not just *concatenating* two lists of things, but we are combining types. Take your example:

```
enum sup = {A, B, C};
enum sup2 = {D, E, F};
enum sup3 = sup ++ sup2;
```

When I now write `E` somewhere in an expression, I no longer know if it has type `sup2` or `sup3`. As you might imagine, there is no guarantee that `E` would have the same value (for the solver) in the two enumerated types, so this can be a big problem.

To shine a glimmer of hope, the MiniZinc team has been working on a similar approach to make this possible (but not yet formally announced). Instead of your syntax, one would write:

```
enum X = {A, B, C};
enum Y = {D, E, F} ++ F(X);
```

The idea behind this is that `F(X)` now gives a constructor for the usage of `X` in `Y`. This means that if we see just `A`, we know it's of type `X`, but if we see `F(A)`, then it's of type `Y`. Again, this is not yet possible, but will hopefully end up in the language soon.

Comment: It would be nice to have a practical example depicting why this new feature is necessary. +1

Comment: Many examples are possible, but think for example of a scheduling problem where we use an enumeration of tasks. You might then make a schedule mapping time to a task, however, you might need an extra value to identify idle time in your schedule. If the enumeration is used differently in other parts of your model, then you would not want to add this value to the original enumeration, but have a separate schedule enumeration. These scenarios often occur when an enumeration is partly known and the other part is the input to the model.

Comment: Thanks! so it doesn't increase expressiveness but it makes it easier to encode certain constraints, correct?

Comment: @PatrickTrentin The main idea would be that it would allow users to use enumerations in more cases. It won't change the models that can be expressed in MiniZinc as you could have used integers, but it will allow more concise modelling and maybe some compiler level optimization in the choosing of the values for the enumeration

Answer (score 0):

More of a comment but here is my example of my need. When doing code coverage and FSM transition analysis I am forced to use exclusion to not analyze some transitions for the **return_to_state**, in the code below. If instead I could use concatenated types as shown, I would have more control over the tools reporting missing transitions.

```
type Read_states  is (ST1);
type Write_states  is (ST2, ST3, ST4);
type SPI_states  is (SPI_write);
type All_States is Read_states  & Write_states & SPI_states;
```

I could make  **return_to_state** of type **Write_states** and **FRAM_state** of type **All_states** and then not have to put in exclusions in my FSM analysis.

[image: Here is an illustrative example of the original problem]

[image: State transition diagram]